# Кто нибудь знает в чём проблема инсталляции vsftpd

Tags: linux, ftp, vsftpd

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: log file]

У меня не как не стартует vsftpd 
С конфигами всё нормально но не знаю что за проблема

[![vsftpd.conf file ][3]][3]

Job for vsftpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status vsftpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Comment: приложите логи `journalctl -xe` к вопросу

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! вряд ли вас интересует буквальный ответ на ваш вопрос. переформулируйте, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) так, чтобы на него можно было дать полноценный ответ

Comment: А если руками попробовать написать `/usr/sbin/vsftpd /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf` ?

Comment: я так и сделали с различными конфигами.но ни........

Comment: что "но"? Если прописать это руками в консоль, он покажет Вам ошибку.

Comment: anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
xferlog_std_format=YES
listen=YES

pam_service_name=vsftpd
userlist_enable=YES
tcp_wrappers=YES
nopriv_user=ftpsecure

syslog_enabled=YES
log_ftp_protocol=NO
xferlog_enabled=YES
vsftpd_log_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log
xferlog_std_format=NO
xferlog_file=/var/log/xfer.log
dual_log_enable=YES

Comment: Что это? Можно скрин того что Вы пишите и как это получаете?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8TeGyMncP9pYkU3WG1mU0twOVE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Зачем Вы открываете конфиг с помощью `vi` и показываете мне это?

Comment: а  что вы хотели вы сказали скрин ну я и сделал ?????

Comment: Я хотел, чтоб Вы написали в консоли: `/usr/sbin/vsftpd /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf` либо, скорее всего в Вашем случае, `sudo /usr/sbin/vsftpd /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf` таким образом запустив демона без использования systemd.

Comment: Сорри. Сперва не очень то понял. Так вроде берёт команду  ну незнаю стартует или не? И самое удивительное когда удаляю vsftpd после вызва с броузерем он спросит user name и .password  Но после ввода показывает autentification  error

Comment: Пишет же: **Job: comman not found** Что за команда - Job? Откуда она вылазит ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том что в Centos  не бела установлена ftp не смотря на то чтоon должен быть by default

sudo yum -y install ftp

Спасибо всем